# Why don't we use word ranks for string compression?

Tags: compression

I have 3 main questions:

Let's say I have a large text file. **(1)Is replacing the words with their rank an effective way to compress the file?** (Got answer to this question. This is a bad idea.)

Also, I have come up with a new compression algorithm. I read some existing compression models that are used widely and I found out they use some pretty advanced concepts like statistical redundancy and probabilistic prediction. My algorithm does not use all these concepts and is a rather simple set of rules that need to be followed while compressing and decompressing. **(2)My question is am I wasting my time trying to come up with a new compression algorithm without having enough knowledge about existing compression schemes?**

**(3)Furthermore, if I manage to successfully compress a string can I extend my algorithm to other content like videos, images etc.?**

(I understand that the third question is difficult to answer without knowledge about the compression algorithm. But I am afraid the algorithm is so rudimentary and nascent I feel ashamed about sharing it. Please feel free to ignore the third question if you have to)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish that isn't being done using existing compression techniques?

Comment: Achieve better compression ratio at the cost of computing power...since computing power is becoming cheaper everyday, but networks speeds have remained somewhat stagnant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your question doesn't make sense as it stands (see answer #2), but I'll try to rephrase and you can let me know if I capture your question.  Would modeling text using the probability of individual words make for a good text compression algorithm?  Answer: No.  That would be a zeroth order model, and would not be able to take advantage of higher order correlations, such as the conditional probability of a given word following the previous word.  Simple existing text compressors that look for matching strings and varied character probabilities would perform better.
2. Yes, you are wasting your time trying to come up with a new compression algorithm without having enough knowledge about existing compression schemes. You should first learn about the techniques that have been applied over time to model data, textual and others, and the approaches to use the modeled information to compress the data.  You need to study what has already been researched for decades before developing a new approach.
3. The compression part may extend, but the modeling part won't.

Comment: You did not catch my first question but it's alright. I found its answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like having a ranking table of words sorted by frequency and assign smaller "symbols" to those words that are repeated the most, therefore reducing the amount of information that needs to be transmitted?

That's basically how [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) works, the problem with compression is that you always hit a [limit somewhere along the road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), of course, if the set of things that you try to compress follows a [particular pattern/distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar-based_codes) then it's possible to be really efficient about it, but for general purposes (audio/video/text/encrypted data that appears to be random) there is no (and I believe that there can't be) "best" compression technique.

Comment: Not ranking by frequency. I mean letter rankings. e.g. the word `a` has rank 1. The word `z` has rank 26. The word `ab` has rank 28 and so on.

Comment: @ritratt so you're suggesting an arithmetic encoding that assumes a uniform distribution for letters? That wouldn't be very efficient...

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right. I just realized that it will be like using a number system base 26. Storing any word is going to take the same space as letters or as number. So my first question is answered!

Answer (score 0):

Huffman Coding uses frequency on letters. You can do the same with words or with letter frequency in more dimensions, i.e. combinations of letters and their frequency.